# Wordpress backend - get title of "settings"-page

Tags: php, wordpress, page-title

I'm currently developing a options-page for a small wordpress-plugin. I've already created the options-page with **add_options_page()** and also filled it with some nice options.

The only thing that's missing is the **page-title**. In selfsame I would like to include the name of the 'options-general.php'-page, because the options-page of the plugin is located in the menu under "Settings" (of course, I could simply write "Settings", but that's not multilingual).

For this reason I would like to get the page title of the Settings-page that's in the left admin-menu.

[image]

Of course, I could just do the following: add_options_page('Settings - pluginname', ...), but then "Settings" is not multilingual.

I need to pass the title of the settings-page + a specific word (e.g. "pluginname") to add_options_page().

I just want to get the title of the settings-page (options-general.php) with PHP.

Comment: Better option is Plugin_Name Settings, that i mostly used in plugins. And its meaningful to others.

Comment: @jogesh_pi Yeah, but the word "Settings" then is still not multilingual. So i need to get the "Settings"-page-title.

Comment: can you share your `add_options_page()`

Comment: @jogesh_pi I think we're talking past each other. I would just like to output the title of the "Settings"-page (http://goo.gl/1NjlHe).

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page

Comment: What if you put `__('Settings') . ' : Plugin Name'`? This way *Settings* is translated normally.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple wordpress code to create simple plugin with menu title settings....

```
/*plugin name:demo*/
add_action('admin_menu','demo1');
function demo1(){

add_menu_page('title','Settings','8','demo-page','sho_demo');

}
function sho_demo(){
echo 'a very simple php code to create wordpress plugin.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get title of the settings page you can use `get_admin_page_title()` function.

to pass the `text-domain` to the title you can do the following

```
<h1><?php echo esc_html__( get_admin_page_title(), 'text-domain' ); ?></h1>
```